# Iterating through a variant array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying, with a form, to enter a directory, a parent folder name and then select via tabs which sub-folders will feature within the parent folder using a range of checkboxes.

[image: My user form]

I can enter the drive, project name and project number which first checks if the parent folder exists and if not creates it.

I then check if the 'Use Online' checkbox is active and if so create an array of the names of all of the other checkboxes within the 'Online' tab. It then gets tricky because I want to loop through each of the checkbox names to check whether each one is active and if so, I want to grab the 'caption' of each checkbox and use it to create a sub-folder within the parent directory (if it does not already exist).

When I execute my current code I get 'Run-time error '424' Object required and the line

```
    If itm.Value = True Then
```

highlighted in yellow.

All of the code used for the 'create folders' part of this user form can be found below:

```
Private Sub create_folders_button_Click()

'Create a variable for the drive letter
Dim driveLetter As String
driveLetter = drive_list.Value

'Create a variable for the project name
Dim projectName As String
projectName = p_name_textbox.Value

'Create a variable for the project number
Dim projectNumber As String
projectNumber = p_number_textbox.Value

'Create a variable for the constructed BasePath
Dim BasePath As String

'Create a new file system object for handling filesystem manipulation
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Populate an array with the online subfolders
  Dim onlineSubfolders As Variant
  onlineSubfolders = Array("online_progCosts", "online_exports")

'Compile the basePath

  BasePath = driveLetter & projectName & " (" & projectNumber & ")"

'Check if the project folder already exists and if so, raise an error and exit
    If Dir(BasePath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
        MsgBox BasePath & " already exists", , "Error"
    Else
        'Create the project folder
        MkDir BasePath
        MsgBox "Parent folder creation complete"

        If online_toggle.Value = True Then
            Dim online As String
            online = "Online"
            MkDir BasePath & "\" & online

            Dim itm As Variant
            For Each itm In onlineSubfolders
                If folder_creator_window.Controls(itm).Value = True Then
                    Dim createFolder As String
                    createFolder = folder_creator_window.Controls(itm).Caption
                    NewFolder = BasePath & "\" & online & "\" & createFolder
                    If fs.folderexists(NewFolder) Then
                        'do nothing
                    Else
                        MkDir NewFolder
                    End If

                Else
                    'do nothing
                End If

            Next itm

        Else
            MsgBox "The online folder was not created because it was not checked"

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
...
onlineSubfolders = Array("online_progCosts", "online_exports")
...
For Each itm In onlineSubfolders
            If itm.Value = True Then
...
```

Each element of the array is a string. Strings don't have `.Value` properties.

I guess those are the names of your checkboxes, so you need to get the value by referencing the control itself. I don't know what your form is called.

```
If FormName.Controls(itm).Value = True
```